# Get access to Google Maps API from a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome-extension

Say I'd like to find addresses on any webpage and have a click on each one of them insert a small Google Maps below the address.

The problem I'm running into is that the GMaps library must be loaded via a < script> tag. But because anything loaded via < script> is out of the Chrome extension execution context, the "google.maps" object won't be available to my content scripts.

Any thoughts on a workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you could do is create an iframe that contains a page to your map viewer. Then you will belong in the context of [Content Scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) and you have full access to Chrome's [Message Passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html).

Since I have created hundreds of extensions, I have done exactly this in tons of them, and some of them are available in my [github.com/mohamedmansour](http://github.com/mohamedmansour) page. I will show an example that I just did for this problem below, unfortunately it may contain bugs. Check my github page above for a more complete example.

### What I would do

1. Create a `map_viewer.html` page in your extension.
2. Include within the `<head>` tag the `<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api.....`
3. Use Chrome [Message Passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) to pass data between content scripts.

### For example

**map_viewer.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/map_viewer.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/map_viewer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**map_viewer.js**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.method == 'RenderMap') {
    renderMap(request.data.latitude, request.data.longitude);
  }
});

function renderMap(latitude, latitude) {
  var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map_canvas'));
  map.setCenter(new GLatLng(latitude, latitude), 13);
  var marker = new GMarker(new GPoint(lng, lat));
  map.addOverlay(marker);
}
```

**webpage_content_script.js**

```
...
// Unique ID to differentiate this content script from the rest of the web. 
// or use the extension id from @@__extension_id__, I recall there was a bug, haven't
// checked if it got resolved though. 
var UNIQUE_MAP_VIEWER_ID = 'crx_myextension_iframe'; 
var latitude = -1;
var longitude = -1;

/**
 * Here is where you want to render a latitude and longitude. We create an iframe so we
 * we can inject it. We just want to maintain a single instance of it though.
 */
function onRenderMap() {
  var mapViewerDOM = document.getElementById(UNIQUE_MAP_VIEWER_ID);
  if (mapViewerDOM) {
     mapViewerDOM.parentNode.removeChild(mapViewerDOM);
  }

  mapViewerDOM = document.createElement('iframe');
  mapViewerDOM.setAttribute('id', UNIQUE_MAP_VIEWER_ID);
  mapViewerDOM.setAttribute('src', chrome.extension.getURL('map_viewer.html');
  mapViewerDOM.setAttribute('frameBorder', '0');
  mapViewerDOM.setAttribute('width', '99.90%');
  mapViewerDOM.setAttribute('height', '100%');
  mapViewerDOM.setAttribute('style', 'position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; overflow: hidden; z-index: 99999');
  mapViewerDOM.onload = function(e) {
     sendResponse({
       method: 'RenderMap', 
       data: {
         latitude: latitude,
         longitude: longitude
       }
     });
  }
  document.body.appendChild(mapViewerDOM);
}

...
```

I hope this would steer you in the right direction.

Thanks,
Mohamed Mansour

Comment: can you please provide full code of this functionality?