# Chrome extension use iframe to show background page in content script

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a chrome extension that can show a map as a popup over the current tab. To do this, I am using a content script to manipulate the dom and the background script to handle the google maps api. The background script works well; I can see the code for my map div in my developer console. I have been having trouble thinking about how to get that map from my background script to my content script because the google maps api v3 doesn't work in the content script. Then, I found this stack overflow: [Get access to Google Maps API from a Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896480/get-access-to-google-maps-api-from-a-chrome-extension) and it told me to use an iframe and make the iframe src my background.html.

When I do this, I get part of the code for my background.html but I don't see any of the DOM manipulations I made in my background script. My developer console on the background side shows that my background script has a div with the google map but my content script does not have that div. Has anyone had this issue before?

This is the code I am running:

manifest.json:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "popup.html"
],"background": {
    "page": "popup.html",
    "persistent": true
},"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["popup.js"],
        "css": ["popup.css"]
    }
],
```

content.js:

```
var newPopup = document.getElementById("chromeGoogleMapsSearchPopup");
if (newPopup) {
    newPopup.parentNode.removeChild(newPopup);
}
newPopup = document.createElement("iframe");
newPopup.id = "chromeGoogleMapsSearchPopup";
newPopup.style.left = x + 'px';
newPopup.style.top = y + 'px';
if (hidden) {
    newPopup.style.display = "none"
}
document.body.appendChild(newPopup);
newPopup.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('popup.html');
```

Comment: 1) The background script must be a different one (e.g. background.js) because it runs in a separate hidden background page. You can't "show" it. Maybe you don't need the background script at all for this task. 2) The content script must be a different one (e.g. content.js), its contents being your current popup.js. 3) In popup.html you will use a standard `<script src=frame.js></script>` tag to load frame.js where you will use your API.

Comment: I see what you are saying. So instead of trying to load the google maps api into my content script, I should load a different html page with my api already in it and do the rest of the work in my content script. Sounds good! Will lyk how that works out. Thanks so much!

Comment: Actually, I can't access the api at all in my content script. It seems like I need the background script for google maps.

Comment: Please re-read my comment. It says to use the API inside the frame script.

Comment: I am doing that right now. I am using the API inside my background script (which is what my frame is referring to).

Comment: I figured out a workaround @wOxxOm. I loaded the map api into a popup and am showing that popup as an iframe.

Comment: Now that's exactly what my comment was saying (or what I thought it was saying :-)